# Finding the position of bottom of a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div and want to find the bottom position. I can find the top position of the Div like this, but how do I find the bottom position?

```
var top = $('#bottom').position().top;
return top;
```

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Add the outerheight to the top and you have the bottom, relative to the parent element:

```
var $el = $('#bottom');  //record the elem so you don't crawl the DOM everytime  
var bottom = $el.position().top + $el.outerHeight(true); // passing "true" will also include the top and bottom margin
```

With absolutely positioned elements or when positioning relative to the document, you will need to instead evaluate using offset:

```
var bottom = $el.offset().top + $el.outerHeight(true);
```

As pointed out by [trnelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638087/trnelson) this does not work 100% of the time. To use this method for positioned elements, you also must account for offset. For an example see the following code.

```
var bottom = $el.position().top + $el.offset().top + $el.outerHeight(true);
```

Comment: I submitted an edit but it was rejected. This answer is technically correct in this context, but does not solve the problem 100% of the time. To use this method for positioned elements, you also must account for offset: `var bottom = $('#bottom').position().top+$('#bottom').offset().top+$('#bottom').outerHeight(true)`

Comment: Weird...I didn't actively reject the edit.  In any case, you are absolutely (heh) right.  When dealing with positioned elements, you must take offset into account

Comment: As of 2017-07-19 the word 'true' in the last line of this answer has an evil invisible character that WILL break your code if you copy/paste (it did for me, using Atom). The character is between the 't' and the 'r' in the word 'true'. I tried editing the answer, but it was rejected. I'll assume those who rejected it didn't read my edit description, there can be no other logical, non-evil reason to purposely keep an invisible character that will break people's code.

Comment: @MikeWillis Luckily I read your comment and since I have more reputation than you I hope that my edit will remain there until the end of time. Erm, end of SO. Uhm, same thing... :)

Comment: @sjngm haha nice, yes I hope it remains in place too!

Comment: @sjngm could it have been reverted? The invisible character is back!

Comment: @MikeWillis No, not for me. The cursor movement is fine in the answer. Maybe you are looking at a cached version of the page?

Comment: @sjngm Really weird - for me it's there. If I double click somewhere in the `rue` portion of the word `true` in the last line, I only get `rue` highlighted (as opposed to expanding to include the whole word). If I copy/paste the entire line into my text editor, there's an invisible character betwen the `t` and the `r`. But, if I click to edit this post, the invisible character is not there. I must be going crazy.

Comment: @MikeWillis Ah, I see. You're right. Well, I was just using the cursor keys in the edit window. So now I retyped "true" entirely. It should be working now for you, too. Maybe the "t" was some Unicode-replacement that just looked like a regular "t".

Comment: @sjngm Perfect! Glad I'm not insane!

Answer (score 17):

EDIT: this solution is now in the original answer too.

The accepted answer is not quite correct. You should not be using the position() function since it is relative to the parent. If you are doing global positioning(in most cases?) you should only add the offset top with the outerheight like so:

```
var actualBottom = $(selector).offset().top + $(selector).outerHeight(true);
```

The docs http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 5):

```
var bottom = $('#bottom').position().top + $('#bottom').height();
```

Answer (score 5):

The answers so far will work.. if you only want to use the height without padding, borders, etc.

If you would like to account for padding, borders, and margin, you should use `.outerHeight`.

```
var bottom = $('#bottom').position().top + $('#bottom').outerHeight(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The bottom is the [`top`](http://api.jquery.com/position) + the [`outerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight), **not the [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height)**, as it wouldn't include the margin or padding.

```
var $bot,
    top,
    bottom;
$bot = $('#bottom');
top = $bot.position().top;
bottom = top + $bot.outerHeight(true); //true is necessary to include the margins
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var top = ($('#bottom').position().top) + ($('#bottom').height());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those instances where jquery actually makes it more complicated than what the DOM already provides.

```
let { top, bottom, height, width, //etc } = $('#bottom')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
return top;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this script  to calculate end of div

```
$('#bottom').offset().top +$('#bottom').height()
```