# Get bottom offset of hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to show the element div then get the offset and hide it again, also tried to left -9999 in style but neither is working.

```
var spaceBelow = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
console.log("Before: " spaceBelow);
$(this).show();
var spaceBelow = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
$(this).hide();
console.log("After: " spaceBelow);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not retrieve the position of a hidden element with "display: none" but you can use the property "visibility: hidden".
Here is the demo of the issue :

```js
console.log($('div > div:eq(0)')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom);
console.log($('div > div:eq(1)')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom);
console.log($('div > div:eq(2)')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom);
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 50px">
<div style="border: 1px solid grey; height: 100px; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 50px">
<div style="border: 1px solid grey; height: 100px; width: 100%; display: none"></div>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 50px">
<div style="border: 1px solid grey; height: 100px; width: 100%; visibility: hidden"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

You should also use the methods provided by jQuery.
[Finding the position of bottom of a div with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749844/finding-the-position-of-bottom-of-a-div-with-jquery)

Comment: Your comment was very useful. You just saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution works fine for me in Vanilla JS.

**Code:**

```js
function run(){
  var test = document.getElementById("test");
  test.style.display = "block";
  alert(test.getBoundingClientRect().bottom);
  test.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div style="display:none;" id="test"></div>
<button onclick="run();">Run</button>
```

Comment: @CharlieChandelier And the other div is hidden too, or what?

Comment: I found another way to find the possition of bottom. Get height from the hidden element with .height();

var spaceBelow = $(window).height() - $(this).find("hidden").height() - $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;